# How to replace componentWillRecieveProps

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm new to redux and followed [this tutorial](https://blog.cloudboost.io/learn-how-to-create-a-simple-blog-with-react-node-c05fa6889de3) to create a simple blog app with react and redux. I've completed it, however I noticed that `componentWillRecieveProps` is [being deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops). I'm trying to replace it with more up-to-date code, but have been unable to understand how to do so. I've read [this article](https://hackernoon.com/replacing-componentwillreceiveprops-with-getderivedstatefromprops-c3956f7ce607) about replacing ‘componentWillReceiveProps’ with ‘getDerivedStateFromProps’, but I don't think that this is the correct use for getDerivedStateFromProps as [React's blog post](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) on replacing one with the other describes.

My current `componentWillRecieveProps` code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            title: "",
            body: "",
            author: ""
        };

        this.handleChangeField = this.handleChangeField.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    //This is deprecated
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        console.log(this);
        if (nextProps.articleToEdit) {
            this.setState({
                title: nextProps.articleToEdit.title,
                body: nextProps.articleToEdit.body,
                author: nextProps.articleToEdit.author
            });
        }
    }


    handleSubmit() {
        const { onSubmit, articleToEdit, onEdit } = this.props;
        const { title, body, author } = this.state;

        if (!articleToEdit) {
            return axios
                .post("http://localhost:8000/api/articles", {
                    title,
                    body,
                    author
                })
                .then(res => onSubmit(res.data))
                .then(() => this.setState({ title: "", body: "", author: "" }));
        } else {
            return axios
                .patch(
                    `http://localhost:8000/api/articles/${articleToEdit._id}`,
                    {
                        title,
                        body,
                        author
                    }
                )
                .then(res => onEdit(res.data))
                .then(() => this.setState({ title: "", body: "", author: "" }));
        }
    }

    handleChangeField(key, event) {
        this.setState({
            [key]: event.target.value
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { articleToEdit } = this.props;
        const { title, body, author } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="col-12 col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
                <input
                    onChange={ev => this.handleChangeField("title", ev)}
                    value={title}
                    className="form-control my-3"
                    placeholder="Article Title"
                />
                <textarea
                    onChange={ev => this.handleChangeField("body", ev)}
                    className="form-control my-3"
                    placeholder="Article Body"
                    value={body}
                />
                <input
                    onChange={ev => this.handleChangeField("author", ev)}
                    value={author}
                    className="form-control my-3"
                    placeholder="Article Author"
                />
                <button
                    onClick={this.handleSubmit}
                    className="btn btn-primary float-right"
                >
                    {articleToEdit ? "Update" : "Submit"}
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onSubmit: data => dispatch({ type: "SUBMIT_ARTICLE", data }),
    onEdit: data => dispatch({ type: "EDIT_ARTICLE", data })
});

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    articleToEdit: state.home.articleToEdit
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Form);
```

[Full Repo](https://github.com/nodes777/blog-server)
[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/m3xp52q1r8?module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FArticle%2FForm%2Findex.jsx&moduleview=1)

If `componentWillRecieveProps` is being deprecated, how should I update my code?

Edit: using `getDerivedStateFromProps`, nextProps still has the previous values so when returning the object, state is set back to previous state, no updates are actually made.

Trying to use prevState values doesn't work in this case because the initial prevState values are all empty strings which are called and placed into state anytime the component renders, which occurs on initial page load, and when clicking the edit button.

```
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (
        JSON.stringify(nextProps.articleToEdit) !==
        JSON.stringify(prevState.articleToEdit)
    ) {
        console.log(nextProps);
        console.log(prevState);
        return {
            title: nextProps.articleToEdit.title,
            body: nextProps.articleToEdit.body,
            author: nextProps.articleToEdit.author
        }; // <- is this actually equivalent to this.setState()?
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alrighty. Here's a working example for your application. I completely rewrote its structure so that each component handles its own set of state and props. The components are also reusable so they can be placed wherever -- provided that it has required props.

Notes:

1. Don't mix `.jsx` and `.js` (see step 6 for fix)
2. Separate your [container-components from your components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0). Also make reusable components -- this vastly simplifies your state and prop logic.
3. For your application, you can completely remove redux and instead allow your server to be the "source of truth". So instead of saving to redux state and manipulating redux state, you would simply make `AJAX` requests to leverage your `API` for `CRUD`ing your `articles` (for example, form submission would send `post` request to `API`, which would add an article to the DB, then either redirect the user back to `/articles` or it could simply return all articles after it has posted and update `ShowArticles` state with new data). Up to you on how you want to handle that. But, with that said, the only time you really need redux is if you're sharing props from two separate heavily nested components.
4. If using redux, add a `types` and `actions` folder as shown in the example below. It makes your code easier to read and more modular.
5. Avoid using `index.js` unless the root folder only houses a single file. Otherwise, when the application breaks (and it will), it'll be a hassle to figure out which "index.js" broke if you have many.
6. The boilerplate you're using is pretty old and you're making your life harder by using it. I've created a [MERN Fullstack Boilerplate](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/Webpack-React-Boilerplate/tree/fullstack) that allows things like: fat arrow functions in class methods, scss/css node_module imports, component-level scss module imports, runs `server` and `client` simultaneously, has an error overlay, eslinting, and plenty more. I highly recommend porting what you have over to it.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/4x4kxn9qxw (unfortunately, the `create-react-app` template doesn't allow `scss` module imports... oh well, you'll get the idea)

Comment: Wow thank you for this! I was already separating out my inputs into their own controlled components, but I will definitely use this. Thank you so much for your time and effort in helping me learn. The point of this project was to learn redux so I will probably still keep it in, but I will add a types and actions folder. Thank you!

Comment: Absolutely! If you ever need help, don't hesitate to ask. Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

componentWillReceiveProps() method is deprecated by introducing a new life cycle method called getDerivedStateFromProps().

Keep in mind that you should always compare current props with previous props like below and if they both are not same then do setState otherwise you will get into infinite setState warning

Replace below code in place of componentWillReceiveProps method

```
   static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps,  prevState)  {
          //Below I used JSON.stringify to compare current props with previous props of articleToEdit object
          if (JSON.stringify(nextProps.articleToEdit) !== JSON.stringify(prevState.artileToEdit)){
        return({
            title: nextProps.articleToEdit.title,
            body: nextProps.articleToEdit.body,
            author: nextProps.articleToEdit.author
        });// <- this is setState equivalent
       }
       return null;
   }
```

Edit:

You cannot access this.props inside getDerivedStateFromProps function. If you want to access some previous props (like for comparison) inside the function, then you can mirror such values inside the state. Then you can compare the nextProps with the value stored in state like above

Check this thread for better understanding

https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#updating-state-based-on-props

Comment: You cannot use `this.setState` inside `getDerivedStateFromProps`, just return the object to set the state to.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I didn’t notice that.

Comment: According to the docs, it looks like you may need to `return null` if the condition isn't met.

Comment: I am new to this method so missed that part. Thanks@matt carlotta

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't think you have access to `this` inside of getDerivedStateFromProps though. I'm getting an error:

index.jsx:177 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
    at getDerivedStateFromProps

Comment: You shouldn't be using `this`, instead use the `nextProps` or `prevState` that were passed in.

Comment: @Taylor sorry about that. I updated the answer please take a look

Comment: @Think-Twice This is new to me too. When I last read the docs it simply stated to use `componentDidUpdate`. Looks like it was added relatively recent.

Comment: @matt if so then what’s the purpose of having getDerivedStateFromProps?

Comment: @matt this answers that it seems https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50054411/why-use-getderivedstatefromprops-when-you-have-componentdidupdate

Comment: nextProps still has the old values when I make an edit.

So in `getDerivedStateFromProps` nextProps has: `articleToEdit:
author: "Test Author",
body: "Test Body",
title: "Test Title",
 

And `prevState` has: `{title: "Test Title", body: "Test Bodyx", author: "Test Author"}`

prevState has the updated info when I make an edit, but I set it back to nextProps when I return the object (effectively setting the state), so no changes are made to state by the end.

Comment: @Think Interesting read. Seems like it's just an automatic `setState` to leverage the `constructor` with not only setting initial state based on props but also handling prop updates. Innttteesstteriinng....

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to heed the warning that React is giving us by replacing this lifecycle method because of its misuse — they are telling us *only do this if you really have to, because there is probably a better way* (including the newer `getDerivedStateFromProps`).

From what I gather in this code, you are rendering a form, letting the user interact with it, but in some circumstance you replace the users' inputs with props (overwriting component state). Its easy to see why this is an anti-pattern but tricky to re-architect without knowing more about the app.

I'd suggest moving the inputs' values into the parent state (or creating a new parent), and change to `value={props.title}` etc. If there is a parent that controls a forms' state in any circumstance, you may as well hold form state there all the time.